# Validar campos iguais

Tags: javascript

Pessoal tenho a seguinte função:

```
function validar() {
   var campo1 = document.getElementById('subtotal').value;
   var campo2 = document.getElementById('totalpagar').value;

   if (campo1 != campo2) {
       alert('O Total da nota não confere com o Total a ser pago');
       return false; //Parar a execucao
   }
}
```

E o seguintes inputs:

```
<div align="center">
    <label for="subtotal">Total Nota R$: </label>
    <input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" size="8" />
</div>
<div align="center">
    <label for="totalpagar">Total Pgto R$: </label>
    <input type="text" name="totalpagar" id="totalpagar" size="8" />
</div>
```

Estes inputs vem de outras funções.
Precisava comparar estes dois, emitir o alerta e não permitir que grave a informação quando clicar em enviar e não peder oque ja esta digitado.
Tentei usar o `onsubmit` mas não deu certo.

Comment: O que quer dizer com "vem de outras funções"? Pois aparentemente o código funciona: olhe este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfcandidofilho/z54tkowb/6) com seu código. A única diferença é o botão que coloquei para que pudesse testar a função.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes da validação, é necessário evitar que o formulário seja submetido usando a função [Event.preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp). Usando JavaScript puro, podemos fazer o tratamento pelo eventListenner.

```js
window.onload = function(){

   var form = document.getElementById("my_form");
   var onsubmit = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

       if(!validar()){
           //chame as funções para valores não válidos
       }else{
          form.submit();
       }
   }

   form.addEventListener("submit", onsubmit);
}

function validar() {
   var campo1 = document.getElementById('subtotal').value;
   var campo2 = document.getElementById('totalpagar').value;

   if (campo1 != campo2) {
       alert('O Total da nota não confere com o Total a ser pago');
       return false; //Parar a execucao
   }
   return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="my_form">
  <div align="center">
      <label for="subtotal">Total Nota R$: </label>
      <input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" size="8" />
  </div>
  <div align="center">
      <label for="totalpagar">Total Pgto R$: </label>
      <input type="text" name="totalpagar" id="totalpagar" size="8" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
 </form>
 
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Bom dia Lucas, obrigado por responder.
Estou na duvida de onde colocar o código, não entendi onde devo colocar, ainda estou iniciando no JavaScript.

Comment: Bom dia. Vou editar o código com snnipet

Comment: Blz Lucas, obrigado.
Até consegui fazer a verificação, mas se os valores são iguais ele não deixa cadastrar, parece que o submit não executa.

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, deu certinho.
meu erro estava em não passar o id do form.

Answer (score 0):

não sou muito bom com JS Puro, pq no meu cotidiano prefiso usar o JQuery,
Segue um exemplo de como você poderia validar os campos antes de fazer o submit do formulário:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function comparar(id1,id2){
        valor1 = $("#"+id1).val();
        valor2 = $("#"+id2).val();
        if (valor1 == valor2) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Total Nota R$: 
            
        
        
            Total Pgto R$:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn-enviar").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(comparar("subtotal", "totalpagar")){
                $("#formulario").submit();
            }
        });
</script>
```